# Stationary distribution of transient states

Tags: markov-chains, stationary-processes

assume that $X_n$ is a discrete markov-chain with transient and recurrent states. Given that a stationary distribution of this chain exists, is there any statement about the stationary distribution of these transient chains?
IMO their distribution should be equal to zero, but I can't find anything about it in the web.

Comment: Transient states are assigned probability zero yes. If your state space portrait is not even connected then the details are a bit messy but the main idea is that the stationary probability of $i $is "typically" inversely proportional to the mean time to return to $i $.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is there a proof for this? I want to use it in my bachelor thesis hence I want a rigorous statement :). Also, as far as I can remember the statement "stationary probability of $i$
is "typically" inversely proportional to the mean time to return to $i$" is only true for irreducible chains, isn't it?

Comment: It's true if your state space is weakly connected (i.e. for every $(i,j)$, $i$ is reachable from $j$ or $j$ is reachable from $i$ (or both)). Irreducibility amounts to assuming that there is a single *strongly* connected component, which is stronger than you need in this context. If your state space is not weakly connected then you need to take convex combinations over each weakly connected component, where the weights are the probability to lie in each weakly connected component under the initial distribution.

Comment: But the result still goes through because you're taking a convex combination of zeros, which is just zero.